# Play dist task: how to prevent conf files to be packed

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, sbt-native-packager

When running dist task, distribution package includes conf files (from `<app>/conf`) in two places:

1. `<app.zip>/conf`
2. `<app.zip>/lib/<app.jar>`

This means that application.conf (and all the other conf files whithin `<app>/conf`) will be placed both in the root of the zip package, and in the root of the main jar library. 
When running the application, files inside jar are the ones used, so  copies in the `<unzipped-app>/conf` are completely ignored.

I'm wondering which is the best practice here: I think conf files should not be packed inside the `<app>` jar (may be some expression on build.sbt to keep them out?), but available in the distribution zip file. So, when unzipped and deployed, conf files can be modified as needed.

`resourceDirectory` seems to point to `baseDirectory/'conf/'`, is this key the one that should be explicitely excluded form `packageBin` task?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your conf file in the following way -

1. Go to app build folder.
2. Type the following command -

   java -Dapplication.secret="mySecretKey" -Dconfig.resource=conf/application.conf -cp "lib/*;" play.core.server.NettyServer .

Comment: What do you mean by `app build folder`? `target/universal`?
I'm actually looking for a `build.sbt` customization, like exlcuding conf folder to be packed in `<app>` jar file, or something like that.

Comment: In your question you told that the upzinpped/conf file is completely ignored so by this command you can use the unzipped conf file instead of the jar conf file.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I was running on Linux, and I dint't see the windows cp separator in your command.