# Play! 2.3.x Customizing build.sbt for Linux (ubuntu server) production distribution

Tags: linux, playframework, sbt, ubuntu-server

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320749/play-dist-task-how-to-prevent-conf-files-to-be-packed) I wondered how to prevent conf files to be packaged inside zip distribution file (actually, inside the `app jar` itself), since the same set of conf files are packed as `<app zip>/conf`. When the package is installed (unzipped) in the server, conf files are both visible and accessible to be modified, but hidden by the packed copies inside the jar.
There is a simple way to address these exposed conf files, by passing `Dconfig.resoure` cl param (ei,`Dconfig.resoure=conf/application.conf`), but I think the duplicity of conf files as mentioned is confusing.

So, I'm looking for some `build.sbt` customization to accomplish:

1. prevent including conf files in `app jar` (unless someone can explain me why is this the default procedure, maybe I'm missing something here)
2. prevent including certain files in `assets jar` (ei, `public/javascript/exclude-me/*`), but include them in zip file in order to be accessible for customization in the production server (when unzipped, just like the mentioned conf files)